# Hexadecimals and probability

Tags: math, probability

A numeric string (`[0-9A-F]+`) is given. What's the probability that it's a hexadecimal number?

Comment: perhaps you're looking for: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Probability question != programming question, in this case anyway. IMHO, this is off topic.

Answer (score 4):

All strings of characters in the class `[0-9A-F]` can be interpreted as hexadecimal numbers, so the answer is 100%.

Comment: Just because they can be, doesn't mean they are..... context is king? :)

Comment: Well.. I guess you could say the probability is zero then, since strings are not *intrinsically* numbers, we just agree to interpret them that way... but now we need philosophy.stackexchange.com :P